# how to use functionqueries in solr as comparison to a spesific value?

Tags: solr, lucene

I want to write a query that for ex. in sql psodocode like below

select * from temptable where price + 3 = 188;

Solr query i try is below

```
 http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/select/?fl=score,id&defType=func&q=sum(price,3):188
```

but i get below error. How can i query in solr? Please do not advice using "TO" keyword.

```
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">400</int>
<int name="QTime">1</int>
<lst name="params">
<str name="fl">score,id</str>
<str name="q">sum(price,3):188</str>
<str name="defType">func</str>
</lst>
</lst>
<lst name="error">
<str name="msg">
org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Unexpected text after function: :188
</str>
<int name="code">400</int>
</lst>
</response>
```

Comment: Wouldn't just `fl=score,id&q=price:185` work?

Comment: yeah that works but i wanted to use functinal query syntax since i will also use it for pow and sqrt functions in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

frange query will do

```
{!frange l=188 u=188} sum(price,3)
```